# How to implement an image gallery similar to google image search

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, image-gallery

I am new to JavaScript and jQuery. I have to develop a website in which an image gallery with similar effects as in google image search needs to be implemented. I am searching for ready-made scripts to incorporate with my project. Where can I find something like this for free or how would I go about implementing it using JavaScript/jQuery.

Regards
Omayr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty specific example, and I would guess most plugins would be more "widgety". If I was creating this I would create the page layout first, wrapping each "page of results" in a single `div`.

Then when the user clicks "Show More Results" you can use [one of jQuery's AJAX methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) to load in more "pages" of images.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have paginate the image search result, you could try by doing:

- assign each image in a div tag (e.g
- Bind the function by using jquery ".each" and ".hover" function (when mouse-over, enlarge it by set the css's width and height)
- There are alot more... I cant type it all...

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can have a look here:

http://forum.yola.com/yola/topics/awesome_photo_gallery_code_for_your_website

It also links an example test page...

hope it helps